# request post method error: get empty array

Tags: json, django, request, electron

I want to post a request from electron application to Django application. After posting, I could get the data of `email`, but I couldn't get `answer`. It is empty even though I post the data along with it. `answer` is an array of objects.

**electron (.js)file**

```
  $(".submit-btn").click(() => {
    var submit_answer = []
    var lock = false
    if(lock == false){
      for(var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++){
        localforage.getItem(Q[i], (err,value) => {
        submit_answer.push(value)
        })
      }
      lock=true
    }
    if(lock == true){
      console.log(submit_answer)
      // output array of objects
      request({
      method: 'POST',
      url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/get_question_lists/",
      json: true,
      body: {
        email: email,
        answer: submit_answer,
        },
      }).on('data', function(data) {
        // ipcRenderer.send("submit-test", email)
      });
    }
  })
```

**django (views.py)file**

```
@csrf_exempt
def get_question_lists(request):
    """
    API to get a list of questions
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':
        ...
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        print data
        print data['email']
        print data['answer']
        # print empty array
        return None
```

Comment: What is the output of **`print(request.POST)`** ?

Comment: @JPG the output is `<QueryDict: {}>`

Comment: I doubt you should be calling stringify there.

Comment: @DanielRoseman where should i be calling stringify?

Comment: You shouldn't at all.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I removed `JSON.stringify()`, but still `data['answer']` returns empty `[]`.

Comment: Sounds like the source array is empty. Are you sure that for loop is getting executed? What is `questions` there?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I've just updated the code. After some debugging, I come to know that the loop doesn't get execute first, it executes after sending the post request. The updated code makes the loop to execute and there are data in `submit_answer`. still, I couldn't access it value in `views.py`

Comment: Is JSONParser from Django REST Framework? If so why are you calling it directly rather than using a serializer?

Comment: I'll check with serializer. Thank you.